# First name put as Surname/ Family Name on passport

Tags: paperwork, australia, applications

My Given name is Akhter Ali and Surname/ Family name is Shah but surname on Passport is mentioned as Ali which happens to be my given name.
 I am planning to sponsor my brother for Sponsored Family Visit visa of Australia. What Family name I should disclose on Immigration Forms?

Answer (score 3):

Exactly what your ID says. If you’re attaching copy of passport mention the name your passport has. If it’s any other ID then write what that says.

Then get this issue resolved before it becomes a trouble for you someday.